# How do sanctions apply to intellectual property and copyright infringement

Tags: copyright, international, sanctions

Scenario:

- Business X in country A sells software with a subscription license.
- Business Y in country B pays monthly for software from X.
- Country A and B are members of the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention)
- Example sanctions would apply to software sold by X.

Would the end result be the same for the following scenarios? 
Would it be legal for business Y to continue using the software without paying for it? 
If not, how would Y continue to legally use the software?

1. Country A places sanctions on country B
2. Country B places sanctions on country A

Comment: Why would sanctions make it legal?  If my country says I cannot send payments to someone, it doesn't authorize me to take that person's property without paying for it.  The same principle should apply to software license fees.  A more useful question might be what to do if you have an ongoing licensing agreement that falls under sanctions.  Perhaps something similar to escrow would be indicated.

Comment: I'll update my question to specify that being the case.

Comment: Updated, thanks for the suggestion! The reason I asked this question is due to recent news in politics and wondering how sanctions might affect the US software industry if they were placed on us.